# Pair element-trigger from a list of similar selectors using classes jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, siblings, lightgallery

I have a html code similar to this:

```
<div class="col-md-7">   
  <div class="row launch">
       <img class="img-responsive" alt=""><br/>
  </div>
  <ul class="row gallery">
    <a href="" class="light-link col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 ">
                        <img src=""/>
    </a>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-7"> 
  <div class="row launch">
        <img class="img-responsive" alt=""><br/>
  </div>
  <ul class="row gallery">
    <a href="" class="light-link col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 ">
            <img src=""/>
   </a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What i am trying to do (with JQuery) is when the user is clicking on **the first** div "row launch" to do something with the link "light-link" inside next siblings ul "row gallery". I want the same thing with the second div "row launch", and the link inside the bellow sibling and so on...What i am dooing wrong?
my code looks like this:

```
$('.launch').click(function(){
    $('.launch').next().children("a:first").trigger('click');
 });
```

*But it does not work*, it always attach the event to the first ul a "light-link" from the list, even when i click on the second div "row launch" from the list, or the third...
Note: needed for a lightgallery example (multiple galleries using classes), i wanted to trigger a clic on a thumbnail, when the user clic on a default large image, and activate the related gallery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `siblings` and `children`. note that to trigger a native click you should use the `get` and then use the `click` function to trigger it.

```js
$('.launch').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('ul').children(".light-link").get(0).click();
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-7">   
  <div class="row launch">
       <img class="img-responsive" alt="pic1"><br/>
  </div>
  <ul class="row gallery">
    <a href="" class="light-link col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 ">
                        <img src="google.com" alt="pic link1"/>
    </a>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-7"> 
  <div class="row launch">
        <img class="img-responsive" alt="pic2"><br/>
  </div>
  <ul class="row gallery">
    <a href="" class="light-link col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 ">
            <img src="" alt="pic link2"/>
   </a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `.find()` function combined with the selector `this`:

```
$('.launch').click(function(){
  $(this).next().find("a:first-of-type").trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. Both this 2 answers works,
So my problem was related to lightgallery
http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/demos/

I have all this thumbnails, and when clic some of this you activate the lightgallery. But, i needed also, that when the user clic on a bigger default image(not thumbnails) it will activate the gallery related by triggering a clic on the first thumb  [lightgallery with big picture activating the gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9xvq.png)